# non twilio number forwarding calls to a twilio number

Tags: twilio, twilio-php

I have an existing mobile number (non-Twilio number) and I would like to forward calls from this number to a Twilio number using Twilio. Is this possible?

Answer (score 1):

You will need to configure the call forwarding on the device that owns the non-Twilio number to forward to Twilio, or call the service provider who provides the number and see if they can do it for you.

Another option is to port the number to Twilio, depending on if you want to make the call forwarding permanent or only temporary.

[Porting a Phone Number to Twilio](https://support.twilio.com/hc/en-us/articles/223179348-Porting-a-Phone-Number-to-Twilio)